# how to use requireJs to include electronJs module?

Tags: javascript, electron, requirejs

i used the usual node require statement to include electronJs module but it didn't work it showed me an error

```
 main.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
 at main.html:16
 (anonymous) @ main.html:16
```

i found later that require is belong to node environment so i tried with requireJs module, but the problem
is that i can't find the electronJs file to include it in the config.js file
i tried with index but it showed me an error in the script:

```
main.html:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at main.html:16
(anonymous) @ main.html:16
```

i just got stucked guy i whould like some help 
and i appreciate that!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `require` in the `.html` file. The right way would be including `renderer.js` in the bottom of `main.html` body as follows:

```
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

And then, you can use it in `renderer.js`:

```
require('electron');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable nodeIntegration:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
    }
  });
});
```